# How to pass non-string values into a prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

I have a few lines of code below to execute a prepared statement with PHP on my PostgreSQL database. However, it fails because some values are automatically converted to string while in my case, the `uid` and `edu_year` should be integers:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO education(uid, year, diploma, school, major) 
   VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)";
pg_prepare($conn, "my_query", $query);
pg_execute($conn, "my_query", array($_SESSION['uid'], $_POST['edu_year'][$i],
   $_POST['edu_diploma'][$i], $_POST['edu_school'][$i], $_POST['edu_major'][$i]));
```

Does anyone know how to make this work, or is there another, more preferred way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to case them into integer:

```
pg_execute($conn, "my_query", array((int)$_SESSION['uid'], (int)$_POST['edu_year'][$i], $_POST['edu_diploma'][$i], $_POST['edu_school'][$i], $_POST['edu_major'][$i]));
```

Comment: Is it possible to echo the complete query statement for the execution ? I mean the $query replaced with correct parameters.